# Actualizar varios registros con un foreach

Tags: php, update, foreach

vuelvo a realizar una consulta con un UPDATE, me están volviendo un poco loco jaja.
En fin, yo quiero actualizar "puntaje_fecha" de la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo necesito es que, se actualicen todos los valores que cumplan cierta condicion y a ellas realizarles un calculo.

Yo habia pensado utilizar un foreach que recorra cada uno de los arreglos de otra tabla y los que cumplan la condicion sean modificados y pasarlo a traves de un input hidden. Pero solo me pasa el último debido a que el name que pongo se repite en cada ciclo del foreach. Por eso (como de ve en la imagen) el unico dato que me actualizó fue el último.

```
try {
    $add = "UPDATE calculo SET puntaje_fecha=:puntaje_fecha WHERE id_calculo=:id_calculo";
    $d = $conn->prepare($add);
    $d->bindParam(':puntaje_fecha', $_POST['puntaje_fecha']);
    $d->bindParam(':id_calculo', $_POST['id_calculo']);
    $d->execute();
    $message = '';
      if ($d->execute()) {
        $message = 'DATOS ACTUALIZADOS';
      } else {
        $message = 'ERROR DE ACTUALIZACION';
      }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
}

?>



<form action="actualizar.php" method="post">
  <?php foreach ($ca as $c){?>
  <?php if (($p['id_fecha'])==($c['nFecha'])){
```

AQUI EN EL MEDIO TENGO UN CÁLCULO QUE NO VIENE AL CASO

```
}?>

              <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">

  <?php }} ?>

  <input type="submit" value="Actualiza puntos">
</form>
```

$s es el valor obtenido del calculo. Y debo aclarar que antes realizo una consulta para llamar a los valores guardados en $p.
Podría alguien ayudarme a resolver esto?

Comment: y cual es la condición a cumplir? por que seguro que eso se puede directo desde SQL

Comment: Ahí lo agregué la condicional que se encuentra luego del foreach. Compara que sean del mismo valor los valores de dos tablas diferentes. Y a esos son los que necesito que se realicen las actualizaciones mediante los cálculos

Comment: Ya te decía que el nombre igual no era bueno en el foreach, desde la pregunta anterior. PHP permite crear arrays de elementos y lo puedes recorrer más fácil https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184680/236345

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho el link

Comment: De todas maneras, la cantidad de datos que tendra el formulario irá cambiando, en ese caso no sabria como controlar el array, por eso pensaba en el foreach